# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space while building gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

How to solve this exception while building a gradle project in intellij? There is no option to configure the memory space for project.

Comment: It's possible to set M options for your Gradle project: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#gradle_vm_options

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to change IntelliJ heap memory size from Main menu bar -> Help tab -> Change Memory Settings -> Change "Maximum Heap Size" value to something bigger than 4096. Then restart IDE.

Comment: This is memory limit for the IDE itself, not for the project